# AWS Cognito and CORS Security Concern

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, cors, amazon-cognito, auth0

I have a web client making requests to AWS Lambda via the AWS API Gateway. I'm using AWS Cognito, alongside Auth0, to authenticate users.

My question is related to the CORS response headers from the AWS API Gateway endpoint, specifically the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header that is set to any "' * '". This article indicates the risks of using the any "' * '" parameter, namely that a 'hacker can coopt our site to request any method' on our back-end: ([CORS Security link](https://www.pivotpointsecurity.com/blog/cross-origin-resource-sharing-security/)).

While Cognito's authentication may prove that the end user making the request is who he says he is, Cognito's authentication does not necessarily prove that the website that is making the request on behalf of the user is **mywebsite.com** rather than **attacker.com**.

**Does Cognito guarantee that the request is coming from mywebsite.com?**

**Is there a secure way to implement the any "' * '" Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header?**

Comment: *"My question is related to the CORS headers in the POST requests being sent to AWS"*  Which part of AWS?  The cognito service, or your API Gateway endpoint?  `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a response header, not a request header, so this isn't being "sent to," it's being "received from" ...from what, exactly?

Comment: It's a response header, received from the AWS API Gateway endpoint. Thanks, I've edited the post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Does Cognito guarantee that the request is coming from mywebsite.com?**

No. Cognito is agnostic of your domain. All it cares about is user authentication/management.

**Is there a secure way to implement the any "' * '" Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header?**

Well yes and no. As you said in your post, Cognito will authenticate the user So that means with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` set, any domain is allowed to make a Cross Origin request, but if they can't provide a valid authentication token, then they get get a 401 error back.

If you want to limit what domain can has access, then you can't use `*`. `*` is a wildcard and hence allows any value. So if you'd instead like to only have mywebsite.com be able to make a CORS request, then replace the `*` with `mywebsite.com`. This makes it so only requests from that domain are allowed. Requests from attacker.com will now fail because they won't have the proper headers.

Comment: I'm interested in how you do this with Cognito.

As @timberlakegregg says, there isno CORS configuration in AWS Cognito, and if you're using their built-in UI it creates a CloudFront instance with the login, signup pages etc., but appears to give no way to modify the CORS origins.

In your example, where exactly might you go to replace '*' with a domain name?

Comment: @JSobell It's been a long time since I used AWS for a project, so things have likely changed since then. At the time of this post you could edit the Access-Control-Allow_Origin in the headers of your response header within cognito. I would have to spin up a new account to be able to tell you exactly where.