# How do I avoid CORS problem when using OpenID Connect (AWS Cognito)?

Tags: c#, vue.js, single-page-application, amazon-cognito, openid-connect

I am setting up a web page using Vue.js together with a .net core Web API. Frontend and Backend are completely split.

I have configured my API to use openid connect with 'Authorization code grant' in AWS Cognito for authentication as follows:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie()
        .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
        {
            options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
            options.MetadataAddress = cognitoSettings.AuthorityUrl;
            options.ClientId = cognitoSettings.ClientId;
            options.SaveTokens = false;
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true
            };
        });
```

This works fine in a browser when I request data from an [Authorized] Controller I get redirected to the Cognito Login Page and after I have entered my credentials, I can see the authorized data.

However if I request the same resource using ajax(axios) inside my Vue-App the backend returns a 302 and the ajax call fails due to Cross Origin Policy. (As the Cognito Login is on a different domain than my backend)

So my questions is: how can I get this scenario working?

- Do I need to move the openid authentication into my frontend
     to make this work and let the backend only use Bearer tokens for
     authorization? But then I need all the openid info like name or
     email-address is in the backend and not in my Vue-App. How can I get them then?
- Is it possible to change the response code from 302 to 401 so 
     that the frontend can react to the unauthorized call and redirect the user? 
     But where do I get the Login URL from as all the configuration (client_id, metadataaddress) are 
     configured in my backend.

Comment: _"Is it possible to change the response code from 302 to 401 so that the frontend can react to the unauthorized call and redirect the user"_ - CORS has nothing to do with authentication: the point of it is that even an authenticated request is rejected if it comes from a disallowed domain. Not familiar with cognito but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48140465/aws-cognito-and-cors-security-concern) suggests CORS can be enabled for it - maybe from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html)?

Comment: I know that CORS does not have to do with authentication but the Cognito Identity Provider is hosting the Login Page in this case. My backend returns a redirect to this page if the user is not authenticated. So Cognito would have to return the CORS headers here but I have not found a way to do so. In fact my c# API is already returning CORS header to allow my Vue-App. 
The linked question seems more to be targeting security concerns about CORS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of pointers for you:
* Your API should not use openid connect - it should just validate access tokens
* Your SPA should implement Open Id Connect using a Javascript library

I have a Cognito sample UI with this architecture on my blog - which you can log in to - see this link:
https://authguidance.com/home/code-samples-quickstart/

There are some related write ups and code samples on the blog - maybe see the first SPA sample and the .Net Core sample

Comment: Yeah this is what took me a while to understand. This is how I have implemented it now.

Comment: @simon I have the exact same setup and encountered the same problem. Could you please share what you had to change to avoid the 302?